# Is there a proper way of opening a window in the center of the screen that contains the mouse cursor?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen, caliburn.micro, centering

I've seen a lot of good solutions to this problem, but none of them seam to work for all my cases.

My biggest problem is that the **WindowStartupLocation** property of the window doesn't seam to work correctly (.NET 4.7.2). In the description of the enum it says that the value of **CenterScreen** opens the window in the center of the screen that contains the **mouse cursor**.

In my case it seams to be opening in the center of the screen that contains the **owner window** of the window I try to open.

I checked a bit what the **WindowManager** from Caliburn Micro does and it indeed sets the owner of the window to the main window of the application if I don't specify an owner. This main window is opened on the correct screen according to the startup location description, but I want to open message boxes and popups anywhere, not just on the first screen.

If I explicitly set the owner to null, it's no longer centered in a lot of cases related to different DPI monitors.

I also tried to move the main window of the application, which is invisible, to the cursor location and that partially solved the problem on my dev machine, indicating that **CenterScreen** indeed goes to the screen where the owner is, not where the mouse cursor is. But on the tester's machine, it wasn't centered at all on the last 2 of 3 screens (1 laptop 125% and 2 monitors 100%).

What else can I try? Maybe related to owner relations, maybe there is something that I missed in the Caliburn WindowManager?

Comment: Holy lack of paragraphs, Batman.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how this editor works. :(

Comment: Place the cursor where you want a new paragraph and then press the return/enter key on your keyboad.

Answer (score 0):

what about a helper window? I am using it myself in a case where I couldnt find any other solutions. Also it proved having other benefits, I remember I had also had to use its onactivate / deactitave events for something useful.

This is my init, together with System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens > screen.getworkingarea > it should do the trick
:

```
                helperW.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                helperW.Top = -10000000; // Location of new window is outside of visible part of screen
                helperW.Left = -10000000;
                helperW.Width = 1; // size of window is enough small to avoid its appearance at the beginning
                helperW.Height = 1;
                helperW.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow; // Set window style as ToolWindow to avoid its icon in AltTab 
                helperW.Show(); // We need to show window before set is as owner to our main window
                this.Owner = helperW;
```

together with something like:

```
    internal ScreenInfo GetScreenUnderCursor()
    {

        foreach (var screen in WorkingAreas)
        {
            System.Windows.Point pos = AddonInterface.Peripherals.Mouse.GetMousePosition();

            var b = screen.Bounds;
            if (b.X < pos.X && b.X + b.Width > pos.X &&
                b.Y < pos.Y && pos.Y < b.Y + b.Height)
            {
                return screen; 
            }
        }
        return null; //not possible???>>>??!/ my screens are more limited than what c# thinks
    }
```